# nested sql scripts and variables in Postgres

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I need to migrate from Oracle to Postgres.

In Oracle I have .sql files calling nested .sql files (with input and output parameters each one) in this way: [nested sql scripts and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653552/nested-sql-scripts-and-variables)

Looking for a similar solution in Postgres I found this:
[How to run postgres sql script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941275/how-to-run-postgres-sql-script-from-another-script)

But what happens with the solution: `\i other_script.sql`

Can I pass input parameters to it? (and if yes, how?) Can I return parameters from it? (and if yes, how?)

Or the other_script.sql and the calling.script share variables?

Or there isn't an equivalent solution for input/output parameters. And variables are not shared between the two .sql files?

Answer (score 0):

`psql` session variables are **session** based, so you can set any `psql` variable inside script, and you can read this variable outside script.

```
\set myvar some value
select :'myvar';
```

You can read more in `psql` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html).